# Junit from cmdline - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, bash, junit4, noclassdeffounderror

I have a junit test suite that I have running successfully from eclipse.  When I try to run the jar with

```
java -jar AppTest.jar
```

I get the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/junit/runner/JUnitCore
at appdirect.AppTest.main(AppTest.java:18)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
... 1 more
```

I know the jar was created successfully since I am creating the logs (programmatically from AppTest) and echoing $PATH prints the directory that the junit.jar is in.

How do I ensure when I am jarring in eclipse I am picking up all the junit jars?

Comment: Jar files are generally not picked up using the `PATH` environment variable, but using classpath mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the junit jar to the *classpath*, not your system's path.

One way to do this is to set the classpath to point to junit.jar and AppTest.jar and invoke your main.

```
java -cp /path/to/junit.jar:/path/to/AppTest.jar com.example.Main
```

Comment: `-cp` is ignored if the `-jar` option is used.

Comment: Damn. I was actually just trying to confirm that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Path might print you the jar's but is the jars there in the classpath. There is one more environment variable called `CLASSPATH` in which you need to append your junit jars and try running your `AppTest.jar`

[How to set classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/classpath.html)

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the other Jar in the manifest of the main Jar.

Answer (score 1):

Believe it or not, it was as simple as making sure I exported as a "runnable Jar" in the wizard and used the "Extract required libraries..." option.  I had been trying to export it as a normal jar.